# socket io erro client side

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Ao fazer a conexão com o server via socket io o browser retorna o seguinte erro:

```
http://localhost:3010/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NOeqJv8 400 (Bad Request)
```

O seguinte código já foi adicionado no server side para poder aceitar qualquer tipo de conexão infependente de sua origem:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
     cors:{
         origins: '*:*',
         withCredentials:false
        },
        transport : ['websocket']
    });
```

E no client side eu conecto da seguinte forma:

```
 socket = io('ws://localhost:3010/',{
        transport : ['polling'],
        withCredentials:false
    })
```

Tentei tanto com o transport em `websocket` e `polling` como sem também já que por padrão seguindo a documentação do socket.io.
Já li inumeros foruns porém nenhum encontrei solução para esse problema, se alguem puder me ajudar, só preciso que o client se comunique com o server, já que a parte de envio funciona quando o client é rodado via `node`

Informações adicionais :
Porta do servidor express é aberta junto com o socket.io dessa forma

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3010
const http = require("http").createServer(app)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema ocorreu devido a uma versão utilizada no client side, quando atualizada para a mais recente o problema foi sanado